# AWS Batch job start too long with Min vCPUs=0 in Compute environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I`m using AWS Batch. After job submitting I wait 10-15 minutes until my job gets RUNNING status. My Compute environment configuration is next:

Provisioning model: EC2
Instance types: m4.xlarge

Min vCPUs: 0
Desired vCPUs: 0
Max vCPUs: 4

ECR image size ~130 MB.

I understand that problem in Min vCPUs = 0. It takes some time to start ECS instance. But why so long??
To speed up my jobs running I run dummy job which works long time for maintaining ECS instance in running state. After that, my jobs run quickly.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a little late but the following threads might help other people:

Here you can find an explanation regarding the time to begin execution of jobs and why batch doesn't schedule jobs as quickly as expected: 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=897734

Here you can find a thread with the issues encountered by a user and some solutions that were proposed:
https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/amg7yk/is_there_an_opensource_alternative_to_aws_batch/

Here you can find a proposed way to configure the vCPU values:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=265573

Comment: Both aws forum links seem to be expired